# What kind of Java member variable is this?

Tags: java, variables, member

I am trying to find out what kind of member variable this is:

```
public class Stone {

    private Size size; // "Size" refers to a class.
```

I don't know what exactly this member variable is. I haven't seen a member variable as a class before. It seems to use another class as a member variable, is this correct?

Comment: Yep, this is fine. Objects can be members of other objects.

Comment: Sure.  It's just referring to an object of type `Size` that's stored as a field.

Comment: `size : Size` is private member of the class Stone

Comment: Size  can be a Class or enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an instance variable of type `Size`. It's perfectly fine and extremely common.

From the Java tutorial [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

> When a number of objects are created from the same class blueprint,
>   they each have their own distinct copies of instance variables. In the
>   case of the Bicycle class, the instance variables are cadence, gear,
>   and speed. Each Bicycle object has its own values for these variables,
>   stored in different memory locations.

Comment: thank you, I forgot about the "copy"-aspect of objects.